# About Euler-Lagrange equation and Beltrami identity. What is the error in the process?

Tags: calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation

If $F=y+y'$, then Euler-Lagrange equation $\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}-\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{\partial F}{\partial y'})=0$ is not satisfied. Hence, we may conclude that there is no extremal for the functional concerned.

However, since $F$ does not contain $x$ explicitly, we can use the Beltrami identity $F-y'\frac{\partial F}{\partial y'}=C$ and obtain $y=C$ as an extremal.

Can anyone please explain what is the error in this process?

Answer (score 1):

If the Lagrangian $F$ does not depend explicitly on the independent variable $x$, then the [Beltrami identity (BI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beltrami_identity) is a necessary (but *not* a sufficient condition) for a solution to the [Euler-Lagrange (EL) equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation).

The BI can alternatively be viewed as a special case of [Noether's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem): The energy function is conserved along a solution.

In OP's example it turns out that there are no solutions to the EL equation.

Comment: Look it's Qmechanic! big fan of your answers on physics stack

Comment: Hi @Bagaringa. Thanks.